# Redirection on primary and staging WordPress site with code snippet

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, staging

I have thus in my functions.php:

```
function trucklesoft_login_redirect( $url, $request, $user ){
    if( $user && is_object( $user ) && is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) ) {
        // Valid logon
        if(strpos($url, 'topic') === false)
        {
            if( $user->has_cap( 'administrator') or $user->has_cap( 'author'))
                $url = admin_url(); // Redirect to back end
            else
                $url = home_url('/support-forums/'); // Redirect to support forums
        }
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'trucklesoft_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

It redirects the user after login. But it does not take into account when I am using a staging site. Is there any way to use code to know if I am using the staging site so that it redirects the the same page / location in the staging area? At the moment if I login it redirects to the primary site.

Ideally I would like the one snippet that can be used for both master and staging site.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a difference in URL for staging and live environment? Maybe you can detect the difference from `$url` variable?

Comment: Hmm. The staging is always to a specific sub domain. I will check. I just thought that the two methods would return the correct slug.

Comment: What do you mean by two methods?

Comment: `admin_url()` and `home_url`